Trying to identify this chip and possibly its functionality?
I applied too much voltage to my Smooth Stepper and I'm just trying to learn a little about it and possibly get lucky and fix it.
I'm trying to identify the IC in the picture, as I believe this took the brunt of the voltage and made the white smoke.
The markings are:
BZN
T1 1
68CY


That is a TPS737 linear low drop out (LDO) regulator.
LINK to Datasheet
Here is a LINK to one at Digi-Key with the lowest minimum output.

@JohnD Looks correct to me when looking at the photo on lcsc.

@JohnD The BZN marked packages are SON-8 (See addendum page 1 of the datasheet), which matches the picture.  Based on what I can see of the board, and the surrounding components, I am nearly 100% certain this is a TPS737.

@nanash1 Indeed- I saw the 2 solder connections to the slug on the two sides of the package, and didn't notice that the VSON version had those connections.  So I withdraw my comment, and upvote the answer.

When looking for a direct replacement, am I looking at any of the DRB packaged drawing chips? What about the 4 lugs or I assume the VSON version that @JohnD referred to, I only see a WSON?

I think the direct replacement is the TPS73701DRBT, but not certain?

@user781675 Yes, that is correct.  I don't know what you mean about the 4 lugs.  The DRB drawing from the datasheet is the correct one.  These are also known as "8-SON" or "8-VDFN Exposed Pad".  I'll add a Digi-key link to the correct part for you, please see my edit.

The one you linked might also work, but I don't know what output voltage you need, the different units have different minimums.  Note the exposed pad, are you able to deal with that? (Hot air rework station perhaps)

Thank you for the additional link.
The chip on the board as I see it, has 8 pins and an additional 4 pins/lugs? on either end.
I am looking for an exact replacement which I assumed could be gleaned from the chip markings.

Good catch!  Those typically connect to the exposed pad.  See DRB0008A in your datasheet.  Unfortunately I cannot find a part number reference, and you cannot trust the pictures on Digikey. DRBR is my best guess, but you may be correct with DBRT.  Personally I would contact Texas Instruments and ask.  They may even send you free samples.

Understood and I don't think the additional pads will make a difference as long as I get the correct package. Just so that I'm clear, I see there are 4 options for the "BZN" package, each with varying voltages I assume, do I understand that correctly?

Yes.  Different minimum voltages to be clear, as these are adjustable regulators.

Which might be just an assumption, based on R35 and R36.
